# Find the rows with maximum average within 8 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a long time-series pandas `DataFame` with more than a thousand columns. I tried to find a rows with a maximum average within 8 days periods.  for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(731, 100)), columns=np.arange(100),index=pd.date_range('2000',periods=731))
```

I tried to get 8days maximum dataframe based on maximum rows average. And I tried in this way:

```
df_max = df.resample('8d').max()
```

and `df_max` looks like:
[image]

and mean  values are:

```
2000-01-01    86.18
2000-01-09    88.85
2000-01-17    89.85
2000-01-25    88.18
2000-02-02    89.58
2000-02-10    89.05
2000-02-18    86.54
2000-02-26    89.22
2000-03-05    87.94
2000-03-13    89.95
2000-03-21    89.74
```

But to make sure I have calculated mean and compared 8days max from mean but result is different.

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['mean'].resample('8d').max()


2000-01-01    53.56
2000-01-09    52.26
2000-01-17    55.00
2000-01-25    51.67
2000-02-02    52.46
2000-02-10    52.61
2000-02-18    52.20
2000-02-26    52.60
2000-03-05    57.00
2000-03-13    53.73
2000-03-21    54.50
2000-03-29    54.51
2000-04-06    50.53
2000-04-14    51.89
```

So I think I am not doing it right.  How can I get `df_max` right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why it should give the same result.

```
{{1, 2, 6,},
 {4, 5, 3,},
 {3, 8, 6,},}
```

Take max then average

```
column max:{4, 8, 6}
avg: 6
```

Take average then max

```
avg: {{3},
      {4},
      {5.666}}
max: 5.666
```

The order of these operations matters